# Click HTML table data and insert into text area

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a HTML table with text in the cells like so:

```
<tr><td>HELLO</td></tr>
```

I then have a text area like so:

`<input type="text" id="txt_message" name="txt_message"`

I want to make it so that when you click inside the table cell, the data (in this case the word 'HELLO') is inserted into the text area (so the user does not have to type it).

I dont know if this is possible, but I am guessing it is and it is 'probably' something in JavaScript.

If anybody has any advice that would be great, Thank you :)

Comment: Do you want to create new textarea in that cell or copy text into already present textarea?

Answer (score 2):

**[[Working demo](http://jsbin.com/aciza3/5/)]**

```
var textbox = document.getElementById('textbox');
var table = document.getElementById('table');
// add one event handler to the table
table.onclick = function (e) {
  // normalize event
  e = e || window.event; 
  // find out which element was clicked
  var el =  e.target || e.srcElement;
  // check if it's a table cell
  if (el.nodeName.toUpperCase() == "TD") {
    // append it's content to the textbox
    textbox.value += (el.textContent || el.innerText);
  }
}​
```

*Note: all the conditional assignments with `||` are for cross-browser compatibility.*

Answer (score 1):

a simple jQuery snippet, assuming you have 1 textarea and multiple td's to click over

```
(function() {
   var ta = $('#txt_message');
   $('td').bind('click.addtextarea', function() {
      var text = $(this).html();
      ta.val([ta.val(), text].join(' ')); /* this add words */
      /* ta.val(text);                     this print one word */
   });
})()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is [`Working demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/NdVga/) using jquery.

Answer (score 1):

To get the value, use innerhtml and a span, more here: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=339864

To update the textarea you should be able to do something like: document.getElementById ("text_message").value = x;